# Access VBA - Cascading list boxes in forms

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, select, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to add two list boxes to an Access form, one is dependent on user input from the other.

My code assigned to 'after update' event in the Trend list (List35) which fails to update the Subtrend list (List37) when I click on Trend list's item. Any idea why?

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim selectedValue As Variant
    
    ' Get the selected value from the first combo box
    selectedValue = Me.List35.Value
    
    ' Construct the SQL statement to filter the second combo box
    strSQL = "SELECT L1_L2_Mapping.L2_Subtrend FROM L1_L2_Mapping WHERE L1_L2_Mapping.L1_Trend = " & selectedValue
    
    ' Set the RowSource of the second combo box (table 2) and requery it
    Me.List37.RowSource = strSQL
    Me.List37.Requery

End Sub
```

The Subtrend list box has a following query assigned in rowsource:

```
SELECT L1_L2_Mapping.L1_Trend, L1_L2_Mapping.L2_Subtrend
FROM L1_L2_Mapping
WHERE (((L1_L2_Mapping.L1_Trend)=[Forms]![Dashboard]![List35]));
```

Comment: What data type is L1_Trend? What is value of List35? Suggest you give controls more informative names.

Comment: When placed on a form used as subform, the form reference syntax you have will no longer work. Since listboxes are together on same form, use instead: `SELECT L1_Trend, L2_Subtrend FROM L1_L2_Mapping WHERE L1_Trend=[List35];`. This syntax will work whether or not form is used as subform.

Comment: If form is set as Single view, really should not need to modify RowSource, just Requery listbox.